# how should we link videos and audios on our html file?

Tags: html, video, playback

```
<video  width="500" height="500" controls="contrlos">
  <source src="hope.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

this is the code I tried on vscode, the video file is stored in my drive c, but I don't know why when I run it, it doesn't work, and I cannot play the video. by the way I open it in Chrome. and when I google a video and copy the link address in src="" the same problem repeat. does the audio and video files we want to put in html need to be stored in a special place in my computer?? plz help me! I'm beginner.

Comment: Most likely because your path has space after dot. Also it must be web accessible and in your case in same dir as current page

Comment: I understood the first part of your comment, but what u mean with "same dir??

Comment: Amm.... put your `hope.mp4` to where your `index.html` is, not in some random `C:` directory

Comment: @HaniehJannesari It must be `<video  width="500" height="500" controls ">` ...

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 solutions of this problem:

1. Keep the video file in same folder where you have stored your html file or
2. Wrrite the full path of the video file where you have stored.

Comment: I tried it before. is there any mistake in my coding or is the browser which make trouble??